# Why can't I pass a prop from useState to another component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So I have an app which gets an API from Movie API, and I have a hero component, it gets movies array as props and when from the hero component I want to pass a random movie into the Poster component(which displays one random new movie as a poster).

Hero component:

```
const Hero = ({movies}: MovieProps) => {

    const movie_random = movies[Math.floor(Math.random() * movies.length)];
    const [movie, setMovie] = useState<MovieType>(movie_random);

    useEffect(() =>{
        setMovie(movie_random);
        console.log(movie);
    },[])

  return (
    <div className="hero">
        <Poster movie={movie}/>
        <Container movies={movies}/>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Hero;
```

Poster component:

```
const Poster = ({ movie }: { movie: MovieType }) => {
  return (
    <div className="poster">
        <div className="desc">
            <span className="title">{movie.title}</span>
        </div>
        <div className="image">

        </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And also the interfaces:

```
export type MovieType = {
        vote_average: string,
        title: string,
        tagline: string,
        date: string,
        poster_path: string,
    };

export type MovieResults = {
    results: MovieType[],
};


export interface MovieProps {
     movies: MovieType[],
      };
```

I guess it should be working, but I have the next error: `Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "title", movie is undefined` in the Poster component.
So I think a single movie isn't passed as a prop to the Poster, but I can't figure out why.

Edit:
My App component looks like this, I pass movies array from the API:

```
const App = () => {

  const [movies, setMovies] = useState<MovieType[]>([]);

  useEffect(() =>{
    fetchMovies();
  }, [])

  async function fetchMovies() {
    try{
      let apikey = 'api_key';
      let url: string = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=';
      url = url + apikey;
      const response = await axios.get<MovieResults>(url);
      setMovies(response.data.results);
      console.log(response.data.results);
    }catch(e){
      alert(e);
    }
}

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header/>
      <Hero movies={movies}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Edit 2: so I did as the first answer suggested and I got an error:

```
<Poster movie={movie}/> Type 'MovieType | undefined' is not assignable to type 'MovieType'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'MovieType'
```

I tried to add default object properties in setState:

```
const [movie, setMovie] = useState<MovieType>({vote_average: '', title: '', tagline: '', date: '', poster_path: ''});
```

And I got an error:

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function

Comment: What does your `Hero` component receives as `movies` prop initially? Is it an empty array?

Comment: Your `movie_random = ...` code should also be inside `useEffect`!

Comment: @ghybs hi! i added my app component in the post. hero component receives an array with movies from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would place the randomiser in `useEffect` and pass `movies` as a parameter. So every time movies changes, the effect runs.

Note that you can't put `console.log(movie)` right after `setMovie()` because you won't know exactly when the `state` has changed.

```
const Hero = ({movies}: MovieProps) => {

    const [movie, setMovie] = useState<MovieType>();

    useEffect(() =>{
        const movie_random = movies[Math.floor(Math.random() * movies.length)];
        console.log(movie_random);
        setMovie(movie_random);
    },[movies])

  return (
    <div className="hero">
        {movie && <Poster movie={movie} />}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Hero;
```

Initializing movie as an empty state object here. It will change once `useEffect` has run.

Comment: so if a movie is an object, should i leave default state empty?

Comment: yes maybe `null` or an empty object.

Comment: Definitely not an empty object. IMO you should render `Poster` only if you have a `movie`. This requires some higher level decision (does the Hero exists with 0 movies? what do we show for an empty array?) that will drive the logic down here.

Comment: @pietro909 i see, so i should put some condition before rendering `Poster`?

Comment: @Kokodoko okay, so i added movie_random in useEffect() but now i get an error like: `<Poster movie={movie}/> Type 'MovieType | undefined' is not assignable to type 'MovieType'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'MovieType'.` Does it have to do something with changing types?

Comment: Apparently there is still a tiny moment where the Hero component gets rendered while the randomly chosen movie is still undefined. One way to solve it is to only render the poster when the `movie` is defined. I added that to the answer. Also left the `useState` empty.

Comment: wow, it actually seems to solve the problem, the movie gets passed to the poster component everytime i refresh the page, thank you!

Comment: @Carl maybe. The answer can only come from the higher level analysis: do you want to support a loading state? you'd rather render a placeholder or is it ok to render an empty poster? these decisions are up to you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your `movies` state in `App` is initially an empty array:

```
const [movies, setMovies] = useState<MovieType[]>([]); // Initial value []
```

So in `Hero` the `movie_random` is undefined:

```
// movies.length is 0
// Math.floor(Math.random() * movies.length) is therefore 0
// movies[0] is undefined
const movie_random = movies[Math.floor(Math.random() * movies.length)];
```

which leads to your error message in `Poster` when it tries to read a property of undefined:

```
movie.title
```

As suggested in comments and answer, the normal way to avoid such errors is simply to conditionally render the child component to avoid edge cases when the data is empty:

```
const App = () => {

  const [movies, setMovies] = useState<MovieType[]>([]);

  useEffect(() =>{
    fetchMovies();
  }, [])

  // etc.

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header/>
      {
        // Show Hero component only when there are some movies
        !!(movies?.length) && <Hero movies={movies}/>
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Of course you can also continue showing `Hero` even with empty data, and handle that case within that component (typically if you still want to display some other data from `Hero`). E.g. you could check for `movies.length` within `Hero` before setting its `movie` state, and conditionally render the `Poster` in the same way.

As for your last error message ("*Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.*" etc.), it is very probably unrelated to the current issue. You probably just have navigated/reloaded the page/component while the server request was still pending, and when it finally got its response, your initial `App` component was no longer there / had changed.